# Does activiti allow users to define domain-specific extensions like jBPM?

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, drools-flow, activiti

jBPM  allows users to extend the default process constructs with domain-specific extensions as specified in their [user guide here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.2/userguide/ch13.html). Does anybody know if Activiti supports this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activiti seems to support it. Supporting documentation [here : Extending Activiti Designer section](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#eclipseDesignerExtending).